# Foreman environment import

Tags: puppet, foreman

I have foreman installed on an ubuntu 14.04 server.

Now following problems:

I have installed many puppetlab modules (puppetlabs/apt, puppetlabs/ntp, etc).
After a click on "Import from..." I were able to import these puppet classes.

Now I have written my own puppet module. I am able to install it with

```
puppet module install andlinger-java
```

Now I click "Import from.." again, but it shows "No changes to your environments detected".

Whats wrong with my module?

All modules are installed in the same path. /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module has a syntax error so Foreman's proxy can't parse it to report the classes inside.  Run Puppet's validator to see this:

```
$ find . -name *.pp -exec puppet parser validate {} +
Error: Could not parse for environment production: All resource specifications require names; expected '%s' at andlinger-java-1.0.1/manifests/init.pp:17
```

The line in question should use a capital letter for "exec" for resource defaults:

```
Exec{user => root, path => [ "/bin", "/usr/bin" ]}
```